# Difference in behaviour of rand() function in C

Tags: c, random

I am trying to implement multiply-shift algorithm for hashing and need to generate a new random number every time. I used a function to do the same as follows-

```
long mulShift(long x)
// returns h(x) for multiply shift function
{
    srand (time (NULL));
    long a = rand() % (long)pow(2,u);
    if ((a>>1)<<1 == a)
        a = a + 1;
    long h = ((a*x) >> (u-k));
    printf("%ld\t%ld\n", x, a); 
    return h%m;
}
```

Here `u` and `k` are global variables. If I call this function in a loop as follows-

```
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
   mulShift(15);
```

I get the following output-

> 15    528638629
>
> 15    528638629
>
> 15    528638629
>
> 15    528638629
>
> 15    528638629

However, if I use srand before a for loop as follows-

```
srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", rand()%1000000);
    }
```

The output changes as follows-

> 638629
>
> 290058
>
> 512341
>
> 826358
>
> 80629

Why is this difference in behaviour? If I keep `srand()` inside the for loop in the last example, it again starts printing same values again and again. I apologise in advance if this is a stupid question.

Also, I'm using GCC on Ubuntu, if it makes a difference.

Comment: Instead use `srand(getpid())`

Comment: don't use `pow` to calculate **powers of 2**. Use bitshifts instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the implementation of `srand()` and `rand()` in MSVC.

```
unsigned long rand_key;
void srand(unsigned long seed) {
    rand_key = seed;
}
int rand(void) {
    return ((rand_key = (rand_key * 214013L + 2531011L)) >> 16) & 0x7FFF;
}
```

Implementations on other platforms may differ, but they're essentially the same (calculating the next number from the current number). So calling `srand()` with the same seed is guaranteed to generate the *exactly* same sequence.

You can mix some stuff up to get a better seed:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) ^ getpid() );
```

Comment: DV plz explain.